# How do i concatenate two BigInteger variables together?

Tags: java, concatenation, biginteger

I have two BigInteger variables "e" and "n" and i want to concatenate them together as "en".. how do i do this?

Do i need to convert to a string first then back to BigInteger?

My code sets the variables from another class.

```
public class Key {

public BigInteger getN() {
    return n;
}

public void setN(BigInteger n) {
    this.n = n;
}



public BigInteger getE() {
    return e;
}

public void setE(BigInteger e) {
    this.e = e;
}

public BigInteger getD() {
    return d;
}

public void setD(BigInteger d) {
    this.d = d;
}




public BigInteger e;

public BigInteger n;
public BigInteger d;



public BigInteger publickeyconcat() {


    BigInteger myval = (e + n);

    return myval;
}

    public BigInteger privatekeyconcat(){

        BigInteger myval2 = e;

        return myval2;

    }
```

}

UPDATE
Have tried the method given in the comments but when converting to use e and n rather than number1 and number2 it doesn't concat them together.

```
public BigInteger publickeyconcat() {

    BigInteger ten=new BigInteger("10");

    BigInteger myval=(e.multiply(ten.pow((int)(Math.floor(Math.log10(e.doubleValue()) + 1)))).add(n));


    return myval;
}
```

Comment: How about `new BigInteger(e.toString() + n.toString())`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the effort shown, the power of 10 for multiplying the first number can be gotten as follows:

```
public static BigInteger concat(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
{
    int ndigits = y.bitLength() * 3 / 10; // Guessed number of digits using 2^10 ≈ 10^3.
    BigInteger pow10 = BigInteger.TEN.pow(ndigits);
    while (pow10.compareTo(y) > 0) {
        pow10 = pow10.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    }
    while (pow10.compareTo(y) <= 0) {
        pow10 = pow10.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
    }
    // Cheating: int ndigits = y.toString().length();
    return x.multiply(pow10).add(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to concatenate two `BigInteger` variables, you can do it this way:

```
public BigInteger publickeyconcat(BigInteger e, BigInteger n) {
  String a = String.valueOf(e);
  String b = String.valueOf(n);

  String val = a + b;

  BigInteger myval = new BigInteger(val);
  return myval;
}
```

But if you want to do operations with the numbers, you can do that directly. There is no need for a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers have already focused on String Concatenation, let me give you another answer not involving String Concatenation. You can take the number of digits of first number, multiply first number with 10^(no of digits) and add the second number. A crude example would be as follows,

```
    BigInteger ten=new BigInteger("10");
    BigInteger number=new BigInteger("1234");
    BigInteger number2=new BigInteger("5678");
    BigInteger newBigInt=(number.multiply(ten.pow((int)(Math.floor(Math.log10(number.doubleValue()) + 1)))).add(number2));
    System.out.println(newBigInt); //would print 12345678
```

Comment: Thanks - i've tried to use this method by taking in my e and n variables but this then doesn't work..

    public BigInteger publickeyconcat() {

        BigInteger ten=new BigInteger("10");

        BigInteger myval=(e.multiply(ten.pow((int)(Math.floor(Math.log10(e.doubleValue()) + 1)))).add(n));


        return myval;
    }

Answer (score 0):

i did this in the end by converting to a string and using string buffer due to the size of BigInteger. I then left as String as i wanted to write it to a file but i could have reverted to BigInteger using the content variable.

```
public String publickeyconcat() {

    String str = String.valueOf(e);

    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer(str);
    tmp.append(n);

    str = tmp.toString();

    BigInteger content = new BigInteger(str);

        return str;

    }
```